# Post request with another entity as a field - use id or pass full object?

Tags: java, rest, post, spring-data-jpa, orm

I have the following entity `Client`, each client only can have one `Trainer` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class Client {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private Trainer trainer;

// getters and setters

}
```

A client can only be created with an *existing* trainer, I.e. I will not be passing a new trainer to be persisted.

Should my post request `dto` to create a `client` be e.g. as follows, then get the `trainer` by id and add it to my entity to be persisted?

```
{
  "id": 123
  "trainerId": 456
}
```

The only other option I can think of is to pass a full existing trainer object in the post request as such?

```
{
  "id": 123
  "trainer": {"id":456} // + other existing trainer fields
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach (passing just a trainer id) seems more appropriate here.

As both approaches would need to check if provided Trainer id (or whole Trainer object) are actually referring to an existing Trainer in DB - passings id is universal. It won't be a good thing when Trainer would have multiple fields to also pass them when you just need to reference a Trainer (which could be done by using id only).

Also, you could use [#getReferenceById method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getReferenceById(ID)) to simplify mapping of id to entity in a bit more efficient way (however will still require handling of exception in case when Trainer was not found).